# Has the hubble:icon Type Class been deprecated?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Update: I figured it out.  This page had the instructions I was looking for: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-views/widgets-apps-files/
[image]

This is my first time using Type Classes, and I'm testing the hubble:icon type class described here: [Type classes](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-link-types/metadata-typeclasses/).  When I build an object table with a string column containing this sample image url ([Color_icon_orange.png](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Color_icon_orange.png/240px-Color_icon_orange.png)), the object table doesn't show the custom icon.  The object table does show a white square instead of the type's default icon.  Can someone please confirm if hubble:icon has not been deprecated, and if so, please advise on how to use it.

[image: object table with white squares instead of custom icons]
[image: object type configuration]